# Update Jsonb Data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, jsonb

I have table with Jsonb field on it and need to update data of jsonb fields.

Data stored like below:

```json
[{"DOB": "04-May-2006", "Code": "2009585", "Class" : "I - Noon"}]
```

I need to Replace Class Key from 'Noon' to 'NS'.

I have also check out existing answer but that all are work for data with single object like below

```json
{"DOB": "04-May-2006", "Code": "2009585", "Class" : "I - Noon"}
```

I need to update in with multiple object []

here is fiddle for the same to try

https://dbfiddle.uk/zyDBkmB7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jsonb_set` and `REPLACE` to update your object :

```
UPDATE content
SET UserDetails = jsonb_set(UserDetails::jsonb,
                            '{0,Class}',
                             (REPLACE ((UserDetails->0->'Class')::varchar, 'Noon', 'NS'))::jsonb
                           )
WHERE id = 0;
```

If you have more than one element in your array then use `jsonb_array_elements` to generate row for each object, and `jsonb_agg` to groupe those updated objects :

```
UPDATE content
SET "UserDetails" = 
  (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(userDetail, '{Class}', 
                            (REPLACE ((userDetail->'Class')::varchar, 'Noon', 'NS'))::jsonb)
                   )
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements("UserDetails") userDetail
   )
WHERE id = 1;
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/zi1OZFzQ)

Answer (score 1):

Use jsonb_set

```
UPDATE content
SET "UserDetails" = jsonb_set("UserDetails", '{0, Class}', '"I - NS"')
WHERE id = 0;
```

See: https://dbfiddle.uk/JJu4oxx8

You may need this:

```
WHERE "UserDetails" -> 0 ->> 'Class' = 'I - Noon';
```

Comment: thanks for response, but here i need to use Replace function

Comment: Quote: "I have table with Jsonb field on it and need to update data of jsonb fields."

Comment: like this : UPDATE "Ecomm_Catalog"
SET "UserDetails" = jsonb_set("UserDetails", '{0, Class}', REPLACE(current_value, old value, newvalue))
WHERE "Id" = 8996;

Comment: As mentioned in fiddle "Need to update I - Noon with I - NS - also update with Replace Function Noon with NS"

Comment: There is an edit link to the question. Dont bury requiements in third party sites. Nb. It is uncommonly awkward to use dbfiddle.uk on a phone screen

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to extract all elements from the array, change the content and create a new fresh array:

```
UPDATE content
SET "UserDetails" = 
  (
   SELECT jsonb_agg(jsonb_set(d, '{Class}', '"I - NS"'))
   FROM   jsonb_array_elements("UserDetails") d
   )
WHERE id = 0;
```